# Extending "Sales Line Type" enum in Business Central 16.0

Tags: enums, dynamics-business-central

i am working on BC version 16.0 
[image] 
as in BC 16.0 option field is replaced with enum, as you can see below that i am extending a "Sales Line Type" enum and adding a new value to it 
[image]
But when i inspect the "Sale Line" table it is showing that the field Type is option and not an enum 
[image] 
So the value i have added to enum is not displayed.

How can i extend "Sales Line Type"? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Creating the enumextension should be enough to make your new type show op in the selection dropdown.

The fact that Page Inspection shows the field as an Option field is just an error in the client.

Could you verify that your extension has been published to your environment?

Comment: Yes, the extension was published. I have found a workaround let me post it here as well

Answer (score 0):

By going through the standard code i have found this

[image: hmdcwj824jmd.png]

the tooltip text i was looking at was not of the field Type but of the field FilteredTypeField, so this inspired me do the following changes in the pageextension

[image]

and boom, it worked.

[image]